# What is the I/O standard for the PCIe data lines?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, io, quartus-ii

I am entering the pin information of my FPGA design using the Altera Quartus II PinPlanner. One of the components of my design is PCIe, and I am having troubles understanding the "I/O standard" associated with the PCIe data pins (one rx and tx for each PCIe lane).

[This website](http://www.interfacebus.com/PCI-Express-Bus-PCIe-Description.html) claims that the PCIe lines are LVDS. However, looking at the example given for my FPGA devkit (which contains PCIe) I see that they are using either 1.5-V PCML or 2.5V I/O standards, not LVDS.

What is the I/O standard associated to the PCIe data line? Could the Altera Cyclone IV require a PCIe I/O standard that is somehow different from the PCIe electrical specifications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did You try typing "PCI Express" in Google and give it a shot to feel lucky, huh? Wiki clearly says:

> At the electrical level, each lane consists of two unidirectional LVDS or PCML pairs at 2.525 Gbit/s.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the transceiver architecture document for your device (e.g. for Cyclone IV it's http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/cyclone-iv/cyiv-52001.pdf).  On this device, the refclk input supports a handful of standards but HCSL is recommended for PCIe, the transmitters only support 1.5V PCML and the receivers support LVDS, LVPECL and PCML at a few different voltages.  In my particular design (using Cyclone IV) I used 1.5-V PCML for both the Rx and Tx lines and HCSL for refclk (I'm also using an HCSL clock driver on my board).